# coLinux strange networking trouble

Tags: networking, windows, ip

Installed coLinux, Debian, sshd inside, pcap-bridged networking, and I can connect to ssh service from coLinux console and from LAN.

Now, the strange part: I **cannot** connect to Linux guest ssh service from host computer, the port responds but doesn't transfer anything:

192.168.44.8 is the ip address of the linux

```
ssh -v 192.168.44.8
OpenSSH_6.2p1, OpenSSL 1.0.1e 11 Feb 2013
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh_config
debug1: Connecting to 192.168.44.8 [192.168.44.8] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /home/sorcerer/.ssh/id_rsa type -1
debug1: identity file /home/sorcerer/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/sorcerer/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: identity file /home/sorcerer/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/sorcerer/.ssh/id_ecdsa type -1
debug1: identity file /home/sorcerer/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_6.2
```

and hung there

Also I use telnet to diagnose connection problems (it shows better that the port responds but nothing gets through)

```
telnet 192.168.44.8 22
Trying 192.168.44.8...
Connected to 192.168.44.8.
Escape character is '^]'.
```

and hung there

Again, I can connect with no problem to coLinux via ssh from another computer on lan.

LE windows has firewall, but I disabled/enabled with same result: is working from lan even with windows firewall enabled (and no special rule in firewall) and not working from windows host even with windows firewall disabled.

Comment: check the firewall on host computer